# Backbone JS fire event upon rendering template

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, d3.js, underscore.js

I'm using underscore.js template function to render templates in my views

```
<script type="text/html" id="friends-svg">
  <%% if (this.model.get("returning_user")) { %>
    <svg></svg>
  <%% } else { %>
    <div id="message-container">
      <h3>You are a new User. Please wait while your Facebook Data is Loaded</h3>
      <div id="progressbar"></div>
    </div>
  <%% } %>
</script>
```

For example the above code renders a div that I will target with jquery to create a progressbar if the user is not a returning user, and an svg element will be rendered that I will target with D3 if the user is a returning user.

The problem is that I believe my functions for creating the progressbar or for making the D3 graph are being called before the html in the template has been appended to the DOM. For example my plotData function is being called when the collection is fetched

```
this.listenTo(this.collection, "reset", this.plotData);
```

I have played around with where to call the function

```
this.createProgressbar()
```

But essentially I think I need to somehow create a custom event listener for when certain elements such as svg or #progressbar div are appended to the DOM.  Is it possible to create a custom event/s for when these elements are appended to the DOM?

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem? If not let me know how I can better it to help with your problem. If it did solve your problem would you mind giving it the check so this will be closed and counted as a solved problem. If you found the solution on your own then just answer your own question so you can give yourself the check. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in [waitForKeyElements.js](https://gist.github.com/BrockA/2625891) written by BrockA. Although the he has written it for userscripts, it may be helpful. It listens for the element and when it is added to the DOM it runs the function. That is what you are asking for but I don't think it is the best way to get what you want. I personally would just call the function that you would put in waitForKeyElements after your element has been placed in the DOM. In a userscript you can't do this because you can't just insert a function anywhere in the execution of the page. That is why this was create for userscripts and not just any script.

So if you went with waitForKeyElements you would have something like this:

```
waitForKeyElements ("svg", function(){doStuffToSVG});
waitForKeyElements ("#progressbar", function(){doStuffToProgressbar});
```

So when you run the code that inserts whichever element on the page it will call the function. This is almost the same as doing something like this:

```
<head><script src="js/progressBarFileToLoad.js"></script></head>
<body>
  ...
  <svg></svg>
  <script type="text/javascript">doStuffToProgressbar;</script>
  ...
</body>
```

But the waitForKeyElements way has an interval (`setInterval`) running every 300 milliseconds that is completely avoidable by the latter example. Not to mention the extra work that goes into clearing the other interval when you realize it isn't needed anymore and all the other stuff that you will need to do.

If you code is running before the element is added to the page then place it in your html after the element is added to the page. If for some reason you can't change when the element is added to the page and you can't change what all is added to the page then I guess listen for when it is added.

Also, if you decide to go with waitForKeyElements, be sure to read the comments in that file. It shows how to change the interval time and the iFrame to search for the element which could greatly improve performance.

Comment: If this is not what you are looking for please let me know where I am misunderstanding what you are looking for. If you need help on any of this let me know. I haven't used backbone or d3 so if I am missing something important fill me in.